# Select null rows in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe

```
Year   Month   Place    People
2021   null    IND      23000
2021   null    USA      34500
2021   1       UK       11600
2021   1       RUS      3488
```

I need to select the rows where Month is null. Month column is of Integer datatype.

this is what I tried:

```
df=df.select('Year','Month','Place','People') \
                 .where(col('Month').cast(StringType())=='null')
display(df)
```

But im getting
`Query returned no results`.
Whats the approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter it like:

```
df.filter(col('Month').isNull()).show()
```

Or

```
df.filter(df.Month.isNull()).show()
```

Or

```
df.filter("Month is NULL").show()
```